# Within Codeigniter, how do I write a view file to a view file?

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, view, region

I have a thank_you.php file that simply contains the string "Thank you." formatted in a successful / green color.

I'm wanting to display this text on a specific region of the site, but not sure how to go about it. Within my main view file, I added the line:

```
<?php $this->template->add_region('success'); ?>
```

next to the "Submit" button.

Within my controller, I have a function that should, once called, display the view file "thank_you.php".

```
function greeter_thank_you() {
$this->template->write_view('success', 'thank_you.php');
}
```

I have the standard $alert, $content, $main, etc... regions within my Template file, but how do I echo this view file onto another view file? Is there some other way I need to go about it?

Comment: What template library are you using, because it's not something that comes with CI.

Comment: @PrinceEnder Is this problem resolved? any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using [Collin Williams' CI Template library](http://www.williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/).

As far as I know, you can't define a region inside another one, so it is better to send the value of the internal region (which you called it `success`) into the `main` region.

- If you are using `$this->template->write();` method to write content to the `main` region:

Get the content of `thank_you` view file by using `$this->load->view('thank_you', '', TRUE);` and place it somewhere inside the second parameter of `write()`.

- If you are using `$this->template->write_view()` method:

Use the following:

```
$data = array(
    'foo'     => 'bar',
    'baz'     => 'qux',
    'success' => $this->load->view('thank_you', '', TRUE)
);

$this->template->write_view('main', 'main_region_view_file_here', $data/*, TRUE*/);
```

And add the following inside the view file of the `main` region:

```
if (! empty($success)) {
    echo $success;
}
```

I don't have any experience with Collin Williams' Template library, but I think this might do the trick.

By the way, If you had any problem, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to to load one view file within another view file.

Just type

```
$this->load->view('FolderPath/FileNameHere');
```

I Hope it solves your Problem.

---

Edit:

Or if You are Tying to Load another View after Performing some action on Button.
You can redirect your button to that controller.
and there you can write the above line.

if it is a anchor Button just put `<a class="BtnClass" href="ControllerPathHere">Submit</a>`

and if you are using some templates Library Please tell more about it.

Comment: I don't want to come off as rude, but you did not read and understand my question.

Comment: `how do I echo this view file onto another view file? Is there some other way I need to go about it?`
What i Posted Above should work Perfectly fine, it loads one view within other view, i use it everytime, and you can load content of that view to any part of page with just using it.

But if you are using any template library of codeigniter please tell us about it.

Comment: @SyedHaiderHassan he is using a templeta parser

Comment: @SyedHaiderHassan My post is more than a title

Answer (score 0):

In the controller, you want to buffer the view output to a variable, and pass the variables to the template. The third parameter in the view method allows you to return the view output as a string.

```
$viewData = array(
    'main' => $this->load->view('thank_you.php', '', true)
);

$this->load->view('template.php', $viewData);

// access the main template data with $main in template.php
```

See the bottom of this page: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html

Answer (score 0):

1-You can pass it like this:

```
 function greeter_thank_you()
 {
       $data = array();
       $thank_page = $this->load->view('thank_you');
       $data['thank_you'] = $thank_page;

       $this->load->view('main',$data);
 }


inside your main page

 <html>
  <body>
  <div id='thank'>
    <?=$thank_you?>
  </div>
  <!--The rest of your codes-->
 </body>
</html>
```